# Use Inherited DataSet In DataGridView [Design Mode]

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have inherited the DataSet class like so

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseDataSet
    Inherits DataSet

    MustOverride ReadOnly Property ABC As String
    MustOverride Sub Task()

End Class
```

I then used this class to create a few subclasses.

It is working exactly as I had hoped, but now the Visual Studio Designer won't let me design my DataGridView Columns off of the subclassed data sources.

When I use the designer to add columns to the DataGridView, there are no Databound Columns to add.

I can still add them manually in code, but I would prefer to use the designer to do so.

Is there another way to achieve the same functionality while still being able to use the design view?

Example of subclass

```
Public MySubClass
    Inherits BaseDataSet

    Overrides ReadOnly Property ABC As String
            Get
                    Return "DEF"
            End Get
        End Property

    Overrides Sub Task()
        'Do Stuff
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that Visual studio checks only one level. So DataSet subclass works but subclass of this subclass does not. It is often the case with other designers in VS.

Comment: Is there any sort of workaround?  Maybe a different way to implement inheritance?

Comment: @MrZander: I tried to find workaround for WPF designers with similar situation but I have not succeeded. Only one level inheritance seems to be usable.

Comment: Thats unfortunate.  I can't find anything else online... Guess it is just the way it is.